# Problems with the size of the labels of the plots in R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I'm having problems with the size of the labels of the plots. So, this is the code:

```
column1 <- c(0.18936045, 0.55010315,  0.23474801, 0.02578839)
column2 <- c(0.20522653, 0.51235168, 0.26060781, 0.02181398 )

example_data <- 
  data.frame(
    rowNames = c('[-2.34898,-0.83219]', '(-0.83219,0.684599]', '(0.684599,2.20139]', '(2.20139,3.71818]'),
    column1 = column1,
    column2 = column2
  )

plot(data = example_data, column1 ~ column2, xlab = "Marginal probs scaledsci",
     ylab = "Actual probs from data", pch = 20, col = 'blue')
text(data = example_data, column1 ~ column2, labels = rowNames, cex = .6, pos = 2.99, col = 'red')
```

This is the plot I obtain:
[plot obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbtu8.png)

So, I would like to have all the points with their labels visible. So, could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For plots I prefer `ggplot`. When I run into issues with the positions of labels (overlaps with datapoints and such) I often add the functionalities of the package `ggrepel`. Example below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(example_data, aes(x = column1, y = column2)) + geom_point(size = 4, col = "blue") + labs(x = "Marginal probs scaledsci", y = "Actual probs from data") + geom_text_repel(label = example_data$rowNames, col = "red", nudge_y = 0.02) +
theme_bw() +  theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
```

The `nudge_y` parameter moves your label with 0.02 units of your y-variable. Its optional but looked better in my opinion.

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your text position relative to the points the way you defined it with the `pos` parameter, one option would be to increase the limits of the x axis range (particularly on the left side), e.g.:

```r
xlim2 <- {r2=diff(range(column1))*.6; c(mean(column1)-r2, max(column1))}

plot(data = example_data, column1 ~ column2, xlab = "Marginal probs scaledsci",
     ylab = "Actual probs from data", pch = 20, col = 'blue', xlim=xlim2)
text(data = example_data, column1 ~ column2, labels = rowNames, cex = .6, pos = 2.99, col = 'red')
```

[image]